# Motorola G4 random no internet via WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g

When connected to WiFi at home, my Android phone randomly says there is no internet connection with the WiFi and it switches to 4G. There is no notification of this. An exclamation mark will be shown in the WiFi icon. However, reconnecting to the same WiFi solves the problem, until the next moment the WiFi is 'not connected' and that moment can take half a day or just a couple of minutes. The WiFi signal is excellent. It doesn't matter if I connect to 2.4 or 5ghz.

Now this could be a connection with my modem at home (modem is for internet, routers are connected to modem for WiFi), since other android devices (Samsung) do not have that problem. I've also tried to connect to other routers at home, but I get the same problem. I also don't experience the problem at other WiFi connections. AFAIK there is no option to not fallback to 4G when WiFi is not connected. Other than check my modem again, could there be a different approach to solve this problem?

- Motorola G4
- Android 7.0
- Latest patch April 2018
- Kernel version 3.10.84